# Accurate Way to measure Margins for Canvas

Tags: javascript, scroll, border, margins

As the canvas uses its own local coordinate system, I've tried several methods to ascertain the global X,Y of mouse clicks and translate them to the coordinate system. I do this by subtracting the left margin and top margin from the canvas itself via either jQuery

```
.offset()
```

or by using

```
getBoundingClientRect()
```

in Javascript.

Sadly, both of these will be affected by browser scrolling. I may just be missing a property (I use e.clientX and e.clientY because I know they're cross-browser capable) that would give me a more definite value... I have been perusing all the properties of a DOM element and none of them seem to quite give me what I need...

I need a scroll-independent way of determining how far from the document top I am to relate mouse clicks to a coordinate system.

...or am I being an idiot and there's a cross-browser way to detect mouse clicks relative to an object? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best method I can find would be to use a jQuery method such as $('#').offset() and then account for scrolling. Alternatively, Object.getBoundingClientRect() can be used, but I'm not sure on the cross-browser compatibility.

Nobody else felt like chiming in, lol.